# Linq Lambda include with child condition

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to do:

```
select *
from empleadores_personas ep
inner join empleadores e on EP.EMPL_NRUT=E.EMPL_NRUT and ep.isap_cempresa=E.ISAP_CEMPRESA
where ep.afil_nrut = <valorRut>
and ep.isap_cempresa=<valorEmpresa>
and ep.empe_xvigencia=<valorVigencia>
```

I've tried the following ways:

```
public AFILIADOS GetEmpleador(int rutAfiliado, string isapre)
{
    using (EntitiesAfiliacion context = new EntitiesAfiliacion())
    {
        return context.AFILIADOS.Include("EMPLEADORES_PERSONAS.EMPLEADORES")
            .Where(x => x.AFIL_NRUT == rutAfiliado && 
                        x.ISAP_CEMPRESA == isapre && 
                        x.EMPLEADORES_PERSONAS.Any(ep => ep.EMPE_XVIGENCIA == "S"))
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

However not work

```
ep => ep.EMPE_XVIGENCIA == "S"
```

This condition does not work

Can anyone help?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: _"This condition does not work"_ is that the real error message?

Comment: It just does nothing

the condition referred does no filter to the query

Comment: I'd recommend using Linqpad to build your queries and also some SQL profiling to see how your linq queries are being translated to SQL. In your example you will get a list of Afiliados as long as at least one related EMPLEADORES_PERSONAS.EMPE_XVIGENCIA is set to "S". It's hard to tell without looking at your domain structure and data.

Comment: If I'm looking at it correctly, your SQL Query and your LINQ query are querying 2 different tables. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes @IronMan84 seems like `empleadores_personas` is a bridge table and his 'afiliados' table in the LINQ query has a one-to-many relationship (probably) to this bridge table.

Comment: An affiliate has many employers, these employers only need those in existing state (ep.EMPE_XVIGENCIA == "S")

Between an affiliate and an employer exists a empleador_persona table

The query delivers all records, including ep.EMPE_XVIGENCIA <> "S"

Comment: Can you post your Afiliados class?